# Why are queries that modify database data awaitable, while queries that only read data not?

Tags: c#, asynchronous, async-await, entity-framework-core

I can asynchronously write new rows to the database:

```
await dbContext.Chatlogs.AddAsync(new ChatMessage(messageString, time, author));
await dbContext.SaveChangesAsync();
```

But what about just reading content from the databse?

```
string firstMessageEverPosted = dbContext.Chatlogs.OrderBy(msg => msg.time).First().content;
```

No `await` here. And inserting `await` causes compilation errors:

```
string doesntWork = await dbContext.Chatlogs.OrderBy(msg => msg.time).First().content;
```

Am I missing something or is it not possible to asynchronously read content from the database? If so, I'm curious what is so fundamentally different with just reading content that it was not deemed useful to allow doing this asynchronously?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Because `First` just is not asynchronous. Try `FirstAsync` instead:

```
string works = (await dbContext.Chatlogs.OrderBy(msg => msg.time).FirstAsync()).content;
```

Comment: Thank you for teaching me about the existance of this method. I wasn't aware of this because it was in a different namespace than `First`, so IntelliSense didnt wasn't showing `FirstAsync` to me when I was typing the query.